# User Agent not working

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, user-agent

I'm trying to load http://m.zara.com from my desktop browser. I have tried with Chrome developer tools to change the user agent to mobile. I have also installed User-Agent Switcher plugin for Chrome without any success. For some reason it is always redirecting to the desktop version.

Why is this not working? How could I manage to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Checkout the link [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/)

Try to download user-agent extension in chrome browser and then you can use the online parsers available in this blog.

There by the simulation of browsers can happen for cross browser access.

Comment: You are answering a very old question be telling the guy to do what he says in the question he has already done?